# Set PKPaymentButton width to superview?

Tags: cocoa-touch, autolayout, passkit

I'm adding a PKPaymentButton programmatically (because it doesn't seem like I can simply set a `UIButton` to `PKPaymentButton` in storyboard). I'd like my PKPaymentButton to be width of its superview. However, this does not seem to be working. (The PKPaymentButton maintains a predefined width of 140pts.) I've tried setting the horizontal `contentHuggingPriority` of my PKPaymentButton to `UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow` but that seems to have no effect. Any ideas how to get a full-width PKPaymentButton that adjusts to the width of my screen?

Answer (score 0):

I've created container view in storyboard, and then added to it PKPaymentButton with necessary constraints.

Here is simple method from my UIView category that makes it easy:

```
-(void) setupWithContentView:(UIView *) contentView 
{

contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self addSubview:contentView];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[contentView]|"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:@{@"contentView":contentView}]];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[contentView]|"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:@{@"contentView":contentView}]];
}
```